# Questions intended to SE optimize the OP's private website?

Tags: discussion

Suppose a user operates their own separate website, say, a photography website.  And suppose they include links to it in their stackexchange.com profile.  Is there then [Search Engine Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) motivation to post questions here? Why am I asking? I'm baffled by the utter lack of detail in many questions.

Comment: Questions often lack detail, because folks simply don't know what relevant details to include.  A good portion of question askers are extreme beginners when it comes to DIY, so they often don't know proper terms or how pieces of complex systems fit together.

Comment: nearly all questions posted here do lack pertinent details, but in many there is an utter lack. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Links in people's profiles always have a "nofollow" attribute applied.

The only link that has the "nofollow" removed is that specified in your "Website" field and then only after you earn 2,000 reputation.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171509/59303)

The reason links are marked "nofollow" in posts is to avoid Google thinking that Stack Exchange is a link farm.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51156/59303)

So, to answer your specific question - there is no SEO motive for posting links in your profile.